# Generate UUID/GUID in Postgres 12.8

Tags: postgresql, guid

I have the following postgres version, its an AWS Aurora Postgres -

> "PostgreSQL 12.8 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc (GCC) 7.4.0, 64-bit"

Is it possible to generate a GUID/UUID in this version ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just install ([activate](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraPostgreSQLReleaseNotes/AuroraPostgreSQL.Extensions.html#AuroraPostgreSQL.Extensions.12)) the extension pgcrypto and you can use the function gen_random_uuid() to create a version 4 UUID.

Comment: The [uuid-ossp](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/uuid-ossp.html) extension also provides functions for that.

Comment: Yes, I used the uuid-ossp extension and I am using the method uuid_generate_v4()